# difference between onChange and onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you guys tell me what are the differences between onChange and onSubmit while using it in react ???

I have search through all of the google and still haven't find an convincing answer :/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event (in React, it's not much different)

Comment: Submit is a form Submission, Change is when an input changes its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onChange fires any time the user changes an element's value.

onSubmit fires when a form is submitted.